# How to rollback transaction on calling @Transactional and non-Transactional method in same and different Service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, distributed-transactions

I am using spring data rest and Spring JPA. I am having one method which update one database table.

```
@Autowired InvoiceClient;

@Override
@Transactional
public String doBilling(String x){
//get date from TableOne
Bill bill = billsRepository.getBill(x);
if(bill.isPaid()){
    generateInvoice();
}
bill.setPaymentDate(new Date());
return "SUCCESS";
}
```

generateInvoice is non Transactional method which calls @Transactional method from other service.

```
public void generateInvoice(){
    invoiceClient.generateInvoice();//this is @Transactional, make changes in TableTwo
}
```

In case of any exception in generateInvoice method whole transaction is rolled back.
Now I want to add one more method which will have list of bill numbers. I call doBilling method in loop to do billing for all the bills.

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = {Throwable.class}, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public String doBillingForAll(List<String> tx){
    for(String x: tx){
         doBilling(x);
    }
}
```

But now in case of any exceptions in doBilling method, all the setPayment methods are getting rolled back but generateInvoice is persisted.
I want to rollback generateInvoice also. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a `rollbackFor = {Throwable.class}`. 
By default all `RuntimeException` do a rollback when using `@Transactional`.

It can be that because you are using and intermediate non `@Transactional` annotated method, the main Transaction is suspended and a nested one is created.

Try to put `@Transactional` in your `public void generateInvoice()` then `Propagation.REQUIRED` should be applied with rollback of your invoices

Comment: I tried adding @Transactional in generateInvoice() method but it is still not working. Also my service class is already annotated with @Transational(readOnly = false) annotation.

Comment: invoiceClient.generateInvoice() calls a interface, which in turn calls the implementation of generateInvoice() method. My guess is that because of that a new transaction is getting created for this method call.

Comment: can you try to use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)` on `generateInvoice()` and tell me what happens?

Comment: Propagation.SUPPORTS execute non transactionaly if no transaction exist. However in this case the class is already annotated with @Transaction so how is it going to make any difference?

Comment: you will check if another transaction has been already created. If you have an exception, it means there is some problem elsewhere.